# public static runtime incremental change - android

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a simple class named A which has two private fields.

```
public class A {

    private String a;
    private String b;
} // A
```

When I get all declared fields from class instance, I get **one extra field** named **$change** of type `com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalChange`. Where is it coming from ? I am totally not getting this.

```
Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0, len = fields.length; i < len; i++) {
            Field field = fields[i];
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Log.d("TAG", field.getName());
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Primary.class)) {
                query += getFromalName(field.getName()).toUpperCase() + " " + getSchemaType(field.getType().getSimpleName()) + " PRIMARY KEY, ";
                continue;
            }
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(NotNull.class)) {
                query += getFromalName(field.getName()) + " " + getSchemaType(field.getType().getSimpleName()) + " NOT NULL, ";
                continue;
            }
            query += getFromalName(field.getName()) + " " + getSchemaType(field.getType().getSimpleName()) + ", ";
        } // end for

        query = query.substring(0, query.lastIndexOf(","));
        query += " )";
```

[image: Here is the snapshot]

[image: Snapshot 2]

Comment: Are you doing correct import? What's the gradle version?

Comment: thanks @MadhukarHebbar. It was discussed here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204714&q=label%3APriority-critical&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 2.0 update - public static volatile com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalChange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556093/android-studio-2-0-update-public-static-volatile-com-android-tools-fd-runtime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was added to support [instant run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run). Disabling instant run solved the problem. [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204714&q=label%3APriority-critical&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)

is the link to android issue tracker